# How can I implement an '&' inside a \left( \right) environment?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I've been running into a strange issue. I'm doing some derivations in  `LaTeX` document, and am using the align environment to do so. Some derivations require multi-line brackets, for which I try to use

```
\left( \right. \\
\left. \right)
```

However, when I want to align my equations with something inside these brackets, I run into errors. Example:

```
\begin{align}
blablabla x=y \left(5 + 3 & + \right. \\
& \left. + 1 + 9 + 7 \right)
\end{align}
```

This runs into trouble, while

```
\begin{align}
blablabla & \left(5 + 3 + \right. \\
& \left. + 1 + 9 + 7 \right)
\end{align}
```

works just fine. Hence, I strongly suspect that the problem is caused by the first ampersand being inside the `\left( ... \right)` environment. Is there any way to get this to work? Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: For clarity: I'm looking for a way around the ampersand problem: I would like to have the ampersand inside my `\left( ... \right)` environment. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simplified version of your code:

```
\begin{align}
x = y \left(5 + 3 & + 1\right. 
\end{align}
```

> I strongly suspect that the problem is caused by the ampersand being inside the `\left( ... \right.` [construct]. ... Is there any way to get this to work?

Your suspicion is correct. A short answer to your question: "No." Medium-length answer: "No way." Long answer: "Hell No."

Why? A `\left ... \right` pair creates a so-called "math-inner" item. What's inside a math-inner item is, well, not "visible" to the outside world. In particular, the `&` character cannot be "seen" by the `align` environment. Since such code cannot be made to work, LaTeX is programmed to throw an error message and stop.

The following code will *not* throw an error message; however, the sizes of the parentheses may not be what you need:

```
x = y \left(5 + 3 \right. & \left. + 1\right)
```

The upshot? Don't overuse `left` and `right`! Fortunately, sizing large parentheses manually is not that difficult to accomplish.